# Nested model association in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, models

I have a five related models:

```
class Courses < ActiveRecord::Base  
    has_many :curriculums
end  

class Curriculums < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :course
    has_many :semesters
end

class Semesters < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :curriculum  
    has_many :year_levels  
end

class YearLevels < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :semester  
    has_many :subjects  
end

class Subjects < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :year_level
end
```

Is there a right solution to set up associations with these models?

Thanks in advance. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Have you got a problem you need help with? Do your configured associations provide the functionality you need, or is something missing? You haven't really asked a question. Otherwise, if you just want to know *if* there is a right way? Then **Yes**, of course there is.

Comment: Your code looks fine! Don't forget to create relations in your database. You need every model, which `belongs_to` another model, to index. And to add `id` in appropriate `permits`

Comment: Hi Jon, can you rewrite my codes, with your codes, the right way?